# Customize path on a per-model basis, for the REST adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

According to the [URL conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_url-conventions), it is possible to customize the pluralization, endpoint path and host for the REST adapter. I have a model called `VoiceMenu`, and the adapter is performing requests to `api/voice-menus/`, as per the URL-conventions. But they should instead be sent to `api/voicemenus/`. I do *not* want to change the name of my model.

How can I configure the REST adapter, for this particular model?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `api` set already on your adapter, you can set the url on a per model basis like this:

```
App.VoiceMenu = DS.Model.extend({
  url: '/voicemenus'
  ...
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! But ... in the model? What if I have a model property called `url`? I see a conflict there ... Is this documented?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with:

```
App.Adapter.configure('plurals', {
    voice_menu : 'voicemenus',
});
```

I really do not like this, because this has nothing to do with plurals, but I know no other way to configure this.